# RESTful Service: Generating automatically entities on client

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-ws, jax-rs

I'm new to REST webservices I build successfully a RESTful service and a client. I wonder, that I can't find the opportunity to generate my entities automatically on the client side. That means I have to provide all entities to client (e.g as jar lib).

Is it really the only way?

I have worked with SOAP Webservice and the entities were generated automatically on the client side. So I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If your REST service(s) support XML, you can provide clients XSDs of your data model, which provides them a widely-supported mechanism to generate your entity classes in their environment.

WADL is nice to define REST operations but it unfortunately does not cover the entity definitions, so it would not help you much there.